How to render text in Lottie if the letter consists of two elements
My task is to render text in lottie in thai language, but when it is rendered, some characters are displayed poorly, since the letter consists of two characters, is there a way to fix this
I do not have any ideas
if ($isStartPlayback === false) {
  let animBottom = lottie.loadAnimation({
    container: animContainerBottom,
    renderer: "svg",
    loop: false,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: bottomAnimation, // the path to the animation json
  });
  animBottom.renderer.elements[2].updateDocumentData({
    t: t("Welcome"),
    s:
      langCode === "ru" ||
      langCode === "de" ||
      langCode === "it" ||
      langCode === "hi" ||
      langCode === "id" ||
      langCode === "ko" ||
      langCode === "ms" ||
      langCode === "th"
        ? 25
        : 32,
  });

